# Update linum and linum-relative background on color theme change in emacs/spacemacs

Tags: emacs, line-numbers, evil-mode, spacemacs

Trying to get the **line numbering right aligned with a separator space and the same background color as the line highlighting** in Spacemacs was quite complicated. Specialy when it came to do both at the same time in linum and linum-relative.

I don't know if this code is ok, but it manages so far:

```
(defun dotspacemacs/user-config ()
  "Configuration function for user code.
 This function is called at the very end of Spacemacs initialization after
layers configuration. You are free to put any user code."
  (global-linum-mode t)
  (unless window-system
    (add-hook 'linum-before-numbering-hook
              (lambda ()
                (setq-local my-linum-format-fmt
                            (let ((w (length (number-to-string
                                              (count-lines (point-min) (point-max))))))
                              (concat "%" (number-to-string w) "d"))))
              (set-face-attribute 'linum nil
                                  :background (face-background 'hl-line nil t))))

  (defface my-linum-hl
    `((t :inherit linum :background ,(face-background 'hl-line nil t)))
    "Face for the current line number."
    :group 'linum)

  (defun my-linum-format-func (line)
    (concat
     (propertize (format my-linum-format-fmt line) 'face 'my-linum-hl)
     (propertize " " 'face 'my-linum-hl)))

  (unless window-system
    (setq linum-format 'my-linum-format-func))

  ;; linum-relative
  (linum-relative-toggle)
  (unless window-system
    (setq-local my-linum-relative-format-fmt
                (let ((w (length (number-to-string
                                  (count-lines (point-min) (point-max))))))
                  (concat "%" (number-to-string w) "s "))))

  (unless window-system
    (setq linum-relative-format my-linum-relative-format-fmt))
)
```

Problem is: The numbers background color don't change to the correct one when I change the theme while inside Emacs. The color remains the same. How do I make emacs update the linum and linum-relative background color after a color theme change?

Comment: This thread appears to be a cross-post of recent threads in the emacs.stackexchange forum:  http://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/18666/2287 and http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/18671/changing-the-background-of-line-number-column-linum-to-the-same-color-of-line   Please choose one forum or the other, but not both.

Comment: @lawlist Thank you. I've changed the question substantially now.

Comment: So basically, you want to run the `lambda` statement (which is buried inside `dotspacemacs/user-config`) whenever a theme loads/changes (assuming that statement works as you intend)?  If so, what function do you call when loading/changing a theme and have you looked for an existing hook at the tail end of that function which you could take advantage of to call your custom function?  I don't use themes, so that's why I'm asking -- i.e., to verify the goal of the question, and to expedite a potential solution.

Comment: Hi. I don't see any hooks in the theme change theme function `defun spacemacs/cycle-spacemacs-theme ()`: https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/blob/f04bb6157f865ed792f6707c65421a3ef02652e8/core/core-themes-support.el

So you meant it's impossible to run this automatically right? Is there any way to at least assign a key binding to run it manually?

Comment: I don't use themes, but it looks like your spacemacs configuration has already created a substitute for a hook in the form of a `defadvice [after]` at lines 219 to 223.  Whenever `load-theme` is called, lines 221 to 223 are called.  Maybe start with putting in a `(message "hello-world")` at line 224 and move the two closing parentheses from the end of line 223 to the end of 224; restart Emacs, and change your theme manually and see if there is a message in the `*Messages*` buffer.  If the message appears each time you change themes, perhaps that would be the place to run your custom function.